# Table in HTML with Jquery, it says: jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...). dataTable is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm doing a homework with HTML and Jquery 3.3.1, and i have a problem with DataTable function. Whatever i do still not working, it only says: "jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...). dataTable is not a function"

I did it before, with help, but i don't have this problem... Also, the code i used before was more short, not a template for a webpage. The principal problem is that doesn't show data.

Those are my links by the way: (adding <>)

link href="css/tabla.css" rel="stylesheet"

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabla/datatables/datatables.min.css"/

```
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <table id="mitablita" class="display" border=2>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Dia</th>
                        <th>09:00|Temperatura</th>
                        <th>18:00|Temperatura</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Dia</th>
                        <th>09:00|Temperatura</th>
                        <th>18:00|Temperatura</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>


<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="tabla/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mitablita').dataTable( {
            "ajax": 'lista.json'
        });                                 
    });
</script>
```

I expect that it works, showing data and all, but doesn't.
Please help.

EDIT: It's a problem with the template, not with my code, i already check out.. I still don't know what is the problem, when i find it, i will put a comment and close the question. Thanks!